# Python equivalent of Java's compareTo()

Tags: python, oop, class, object

I'm doing a project in Python (3.2) for which I need to compare user defined objects.  I'm used to OOP in Java, where one would define a `compareTo()` method in the class that specifies the natural ordering of that class, as in the example below:

```
public class Foo {
    int a, b;

    public Foo(int aa, int bb) {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo that) {
        // return a negative number if this < that
        // return 0 if this == that
        // return a positive number if this > that

        if (this.a == that.a) return this.b - that.b;
        else return this.a - that.a;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to classes/objects in Python, so I'd like to know what is the "pythonic" way to define the natural ordering of a class?

Comment: You mean like [`__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can implement the special methods `__lt__`, `__gt__` etc. to implement the default operators for custom types. See more about them in the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__ (self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if self.a == other.a:
            return self.b < other.b
        return self.a < other.b

    def __gt__ (self, other):
        return other.__lt__(self)

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.a == other.b and self.b == other.b

    def __ne__ (self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Or as said by stranac in the comments, you can use the [`total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator to save some typing:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class Foo:
    def __init__ (self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if self.a == other.a:
            return self.b < other.b
        return self.a < other.b

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.a == other.b and self.b == other.b
```

Comment: You could also just define `__lt__` and `__eq__` and use the `functools.total_ordering` decorator.

Comment: In Python 2 `__gt__` is automatically `not __lt__` if not provided (just tested it). Strange that the documentation says otherwise. Someone want to test it on Python 3, maybe @stranac ?

Comment: You are right, but it might be possible that the documentation actually only refers to the inverse, i.e. `not (a < b) == (a >= b)` (where the latter will raise an exception if not defined), so I guess it does swap the parameters if possible.

Comment: @ms4py: I'm guessing the docs are just saying that if `__gt__` is `False`, that doesn't necessarily mean `__lt__` is `True`. They could be defined in a way that both are `True`/`False`.

Answer (score 7):

Python has a similar function: [`__cmp__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).

I now see you're asking about Python 3.  [Their "whats new" suggests](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html):

```
The cmp() function should be treated as gone, and the __cmp__() special method 
is no longer supported. Use __lt__() for sorting, __eq__() with __hash__(), and 
other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the cmp() functionality, 
you could use the expression (a > b) - (a < b) as the equivalent for cmp(a, b).)
```

So it seems you could always do something like

```
def compareTo(self, that):
    return ((self > that) - (self < that))
```

or

```
@classmethod
def compare(cls, a, b):
    return ((a > b) - (a < b))
```

after implementing `__gt__()` and `__lt__()`.

Which you would then use like:

```
f1 = Foo(1,1)
f2 = Foo(2,2)

f1.compareTo(f2)
Foo.compare(f1,f2)
```

This would give you equivalent functionality.

Comment: `__cmp__` does no longer exist in Python 3, and OP is asking about Python 3.